# Dependency 'junit:junit-jupiter:5.5.2' not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am using intelij and tried to use junit dependency. But when I am adding the dependency in my pom file, it gives me the following error. Why is this happening?

```
Dependency 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2' not found
```

My pom..xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**SOLVED**

maven -> reload all projects

Comment: I believe your artifactId is wrong. There's `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine`

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.4.0 Here's the dependency.

Comment: Indeed, didn't know there was an aggregator. Thanks for pointing that out. Are you using a custom Maven repository in either your POM or your Maven settings? It could be that you have a custom repository that is serving as mirror, but doesn't contain this artifact.

Comment: Thanks for adding the solution directly in the question!!! Worked like a charm!